# Is it okay to put an HTML document inside the <body> of another HTML document?

Tags: php, html, yii

**Is it "okay" to have an HTML document embedded inside the body tag of another HTML document?**
*The reason why I want to do this is so that I can call a javascript body onload -- I cannot do that in the main HTML document because the main HTML code is dynamically generated by a controller (Yii) that controls other pages and I do not want to edit it.*

*By the way, I tried it and it seems to work fine now, but I just want to be sure that the page will not break in the future for whatever reason.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>    
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript>
        function somefunction(){
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:somefunction()">    
    </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is attach an `onload` event, you're going about it the wrong way.

All you have to do is add a `script` element that attaches an onload event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function somefunction()
  {
    ...do stuff...
  }


  document.body.onload = somefunction;

</script>
```

Alternatively, if you've appended your JS files at the *bottom* of the page, they will be able to interact with the DOM similarly to how `onload` works. The reason to use `onload` is only so that the elements defined within the web page have been added to the DOM by the time a function is executed. If your scripts are after your content, the elements will be in the DOM.

Comment: Also note that `onload` will wait for the page's assets, like images, to load before firing. Putting the script at the bottom of `<body>` not only guarantees DOM access like `onload` does, but also fires first.

Comment: Scripts placed a the bottom of the page do not execute identically to `onload` the primary difference being the first script at the bottom wont have access to: subsequent scripts, the code they contain, any functionality they add. `onload` means *everything* has loaded, which allows for cross-script references with impunity. `document.onreadystatechange` is another function to look into as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's bad HTML.

Just put your JavaScript at the bottom before `</body>`.

Comment: it certainly isn't valid HTML, but I can't think of a browser that would choke on it either.