# Having trouble with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on this site:
http://www.millersmartialarts.no/

At the moment, I've used LavaLamp on the navigation.
LavaLamp script from: lavalamp for jquery lovers

Problem 1:
It doesn't appear.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ripsraps/uGC2V/

Have had alot of problems with jQuery for this site. Especially getting something as simple as a lightbox feature running properly.

Comment: plz provide some code so that we can help you

Comment: Please reproduce the problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, so we can see your code in action. Also, working to reproduce the problem might also help you work out what the problem is.

Comment: Add in a Fiddle so we can help you. I've used this lavalamp before on some sites

Comment: The lavalamp scrpt:
http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Comment: A demo should be [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), not the *whole page.* The point is to work out where the problem is, and show us that particular section/component.

Comment: the fiddle doesn't render the same as the website, also you shouldn't use frame based forwarding on your site.

Comment: As for Fiddle. Never used it before, I got 0 knowledge on how to use it.
I think I solved the problem with the links that are not directing me to other pages, by adding alert(event+el); to the click:function.

As of now, I think the problem is to get the lavalamp to show.

New fiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/ripsraps/uGC2V/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is running correctly but you haven't set up the css to style the background lava graphic.

You need to use add a class called backLava to your css file.

Search in here for some examples:

- http://nixbox.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/demos/original.css

Answer (score 1):

1. You have one file missing :

   http://ripsraps.com/millers/script/images/bg-light.png
2. You have these JavasScript errors :

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://ripsraps.com/millers/ from frame with URL
>   https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=no&geocode=&q=Waldemar+Thranes+gate+86a,+Oslo,+NO.&aq=t&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=41.767874,117.158203&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Waldemar+Thranes+gate+86,+Gr%C3%BCnerl%C3%B8kka,+0175+Oslo,+Norge&t=m&z=14&ll=59.928304,10.753733&output=embed.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: I *love* the appropriateness of someone with your user name answering a question regarding a martial-arts site... =)

Answer (score 0):

you are embedding a complete page within your homepage,

you may check this [Multiple <html><body> </html></body> in same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad answer because I don't have a great deal of jQuery experience but there are issues using jQuery with frames which *may* be applicable to your case and which you may want to read up on. I don't know for a fact that it has anything to do with anything but it would certainly explain the "lot of problems".

http://iainhoult.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/using-jquery-with-frames.html

Answer (score 0):

Your menu and map loads.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RcFrS/13/)

I removed almost everything and changed the `.navlinkplacer` class float property to left as the width of your elements it larger than the wide of the default jsfiddle result page.

The map also loads, but again i added a `style="float:left;"` to the `lokalet` class to show it properly in jsfiddle.

If you keep having troubles with all your code,

> divide then conquer.