# How to insert div to the top of browser body in javascript in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am new to firefox extension and did not know how to develop toolbar like div in javascript/content script and want to fix it to the top of body(want to push body down). please help.

```
  var toolbarHeight = 40;

   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.id = "myToolbar";
   div.textContent = "  ";
   var st = div.style;
   st.display = "block";
   st.top = "0px";
   st.left = "0px";
    st.width = "100%";
     st.height = toolbarHeight + "px";
   st.background = "#F0F0F0";
   st.color = "grey";
   st.fontStyle = "italic";
   st.position = "fixed";
    document.body.style.webkitTransform = "translateY(" + toolbarHeight + "px)";
    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

****2 UPDATE:**

```
I have seen update this works but div also moves with body
because document.documentElement.appendChild(div); 

is not working and with document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild); 
div also moves down becuase of inserting in body
```

This is normal because you assign in a `body` the style `document.body.style.webkitTransform =         // Chrome, Opera, Safari
  document.body.style.msTransform =           // IE 9
  document.body.style.transform = "translateY(" + toolbarHeight + "px)";`

The problem is a style.

Now there is a one possibility where you not assign this style to `<body>` but only on `<div>` and you can create inside the `body` two `<div>`.

**NOTE** You cannot create two `<body>` in a file HTML because it 's a valid document HTML [INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file)

Where the first `<div>` is the created of script that we discuss and other the rest of the `<body>` in the `<div>`.
Final you can assign the style on a div using `document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.webkitTransform =document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.msTransform =document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.transform = "translateY(" + toolbarHeight + "px)";`

And I shocked on the last comment.
****UPDATE:**
With the comment I understand you problem.
I copy new you script and paste on my notebook.
I open the file HTML on Firefox and Chromium (this is a name of Chrome on Ubuntu).
You can see the output and difference on [imguru](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD5Im.png).
Now the problem is only on `document.body.parent.style.webkitTransform='translateY(40px)';`

I find why not function and this is not supported on `Firefox`, `IE` and `OPERA`.
You see on the [site](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-webkit-transform)

Now I change it with

```
document.body.style.webkitTransform =         // Chrome, Opera, Safari
  document.body.style.msTransform =           // IE 9
  document.body.style.transform = "translateY(" + toolbarHeight + "px)";
```

And the output is equal on Chrome. [IMGURU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7uFH.png)

**OLD:**

I take you script and work in my notebook.

Inside the code there is a error on `document.body.parent.style.webkitTransform='translateY(40px)';` and the error is:

```
TypeError: document.body.parent is undefined
```

This I not know that is and I delete.
Now I have other error `TypeError: document.body is null` on `var div = document.createElement("div");`
I search on google and I fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916747/why-is-document-body-null-in-my-javascript)
Now I insert `window.onload{ }` with inside you script and I insert the tag 
 for push body down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
  //document.body.parent.style.webkitTransform ='translateY(40px)';
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var br=document.createElement("br");
  div.id="divs";
  div.style.display='block';
  div.style.width = "600px";
  div.style.height = "100px";
  div.style.background = "#C2E2FF";
  div.style.color = "grey";
  div.innerHTML = "my div";
  document.body.insertBefore(br, document.body.firstChild);
  document.getElementById("divs").style.fontStyle = 'italic';
  document.getElementById("divs").style.position = "fixed";

  }</script>
```

The output not view the body because the error (I say the error but this is not error) on style="fixed" because "replace" the  (The element is positioned relative to the browser window).
I remove this and the output is correct.

I think that you have a problem with position and I suggest for you of use Firebug (tool of firefox and chrome) for find error

For information on the position you go on this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Final [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/DuxFj/1/)

Comment: i dont understand what are u saying i want div which stick to top and  body pf browser pushes down and it stick to top while scrolling.

Comment: Aaahh you want to use a scrool with the div??

Comment: actually i have a code which is running fine in chrome but not in firefox. actually i want that in my etension when i scroll down or up a webpage div remain fixed it should not scroll down. I have also changed my code .

Comment: In fact I have a firefox and before you not say the scroll

Comment: i have seen update this works but div also moves with body because     document.documentElement.appendChild(div); is not working and with     document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild); div also moves down becuase of inserting in body

Comment: how can i append it to document only as in chrome??

Comment: you can contact me on mrk1989@hotmail.it on MSN or Skype if you want more helping from me