# HTML :: Anyway to 'split' the body tag?

Tags: java, html, css, split, styles

Been a long time lurker of this site (came in handy on a number of occasions) but today I have the need to post my own question (knew this day would come).

First off I'm just learning HTML and whilst coming up with designs for a coursework project I have ran into a problem.

What I want to do is to have the page 'split' into two sections, by split I mean have a navigation menu and lets say a title in one half and then the main content area in the other half, but this design I have, it has rounded corners on all corners, this means that I am looking for a way to create two 'body' tags of kind or something similar which would allow the following;

[image: Mockup]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/ca9c6572ed5af4dd928e02f0dba83fac.png))</sub>

Is there anyway to get something like the picture above?

Thanks

Jack

Comment: Have you tried using divs?

Comment: Yes, but because the divs are inside the body tag, rounding the div doesn't actually have any effect. Unless I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's just basic CSS, with styled divs or sections etc. Show us the code you are using and we'll show what's going wrong.

Comment: First off, html document can only have a single body tag which contains the whole document. So "head" and "body" in html doesn't stand for visible page header and body. Everything you see on a page, all kinds of logical headers, menus and sections are created with other markup. Div tags for example.

Comment: So I was doing it wrong then, care to share more? @ralph.m

Comment: Show us what you're doing so far, say on CodePen.

Comment: See this for an example http://jsfiddle.net/A67nV/

Comment: I've figured it out now. http://gyazo.com/15ef90b97d2dafcd420f73136c53898c :). Thanks the explanation from @Ivarpoiss jogged my memory of how it actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035627/2999215), you **can't** have more than one `<body>` tag.

To create sections inside your body, you can use `<div>` tags instead (or other new html5 tags like `<nav>`, `<article>`, etc.).

For what you want, try something like this:

```html
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <!-- Navigation -->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Tutorial -->
    </div>
</body>
```

And then for your CSS:

```css
#nav, #content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/MW9MN/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

An html page can only have a single "body". What you're probably looking for is a "div" element, otherwise known as a "HTML Document Division Element". For more details, check out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you shouldnt create two body tags. Instead in a body you can add two  tags, and and put your contents inside divs. If you want to round the border of divs, you should use some css code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    #up
    {
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    background:#dddddd;
    width:90%;
    margin:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
    }
    #down
    {
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding:10px 40px;
    margin:5px;
    background:#dddddd;
    width:90%;
    border-top-left-radius:2em;
    border-top-right-radius:2em;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='up'>
MAIN PART 1
The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.
</div>
    <div id='down'>

MAIN PART 2
The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this once. It's actually a common practice in ASP.NET because they work in sections (placeholders) and a masterpage

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <style>
      .body1, .body2{
     margin:0 auto;
     height:200px;
       }
      .body1{
      background-color:blue;
      width:1200px;
       }
      .body2{
      background-color:red;
      width:1200px;
       }

     </style>
   </head>

      <section class="body1"> 1 </section>
      <section class="body2"> 2 </section>

   </html>
```