# Edit HTML file using MVC w/ ACE Editor

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a page which can read the contents of a HTML file and output it's data to the screen.

To get the HTML files data I am doing:

```
ViewBag.PageHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"W:\1.html");
```

Then in the View, I have the following

```
 @Html.Raw(ViewBag.PageHtml)
```

The HTML data is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The body</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result of the Html.Raw is this, some how the `<html><head>` etc tags are being removed.

```
<title>Test Title</title>
<p>The body</p>
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is, and how I can prevent it from happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this myself, the first step was to add a hidden textarea field.

```
<textarea id="templateHtml" style="display: none">@ViewBag.PageHtml</textarea>
```

I left the div empty like this

```
<div id="txtArea"></div>
```

Then I just used the value of the text area as the value of the ACE Editor.

```
var el = document.getElementById("txtArea");
editor = ace.edit(el);
editor.session.setValue($("#templateHtml").val());
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.setOption("showPrintMargin", false);
```

Comment: Glad to see you solved it! This was a more editor-specific question, would have been nice if you were more specific in your question. Either way, good work!

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting to see.

It seems as if `@Html.Raw` sanitizes the input; which is usually a good idea.
In your case however; it seems to not help you that much.

However, having multiple `<html>`and `<body>` tags is not allowed. See this question: [Multiple <html><body> </html></body> in same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file)

If you *know* that these tags are removed, then simply re-add them. With that said however; i think you are having the wrong approach to this.

If all you want to do is return a static HTML-file from a HTML-document, then you could just serve this "as is". If you are looking to do this "dynamically" somehow (maybe from a database or similar) then you should probably do it *directly from the controller* using a `ContentResult`.

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ContentResult ServePureHtml()
        {
            string htmlData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"W:\1.html");

            return Content(htmlData, "text/html");
        }
    }
}
```

You could use this as a partial result as well. Using `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction`

For instance

```
<!-- ... -->
<div class="editor-content">
    @{
         Html.RenderAction("ServePureHtml", "Home");
    }

</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Also, be cautious of using the ViewBag. Its behavior is usually not amazing.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns the exact same result

Comment: But are you trying to add a full HTML-document to a already existing document? This is (as I stated) not allowed. If you _must_ add the entire document (including the html, head and body tags), then use a iframe. Your question is still a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Sorry for the fuzzyness, my main goal is to edit the contents of the HTML. So no, I am not adding two sets of HTML tags etc, I just want to allow people to edit the contents of the .html file from the browser.