# CSS responsive design: hiding doesn't make a page from rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Suppose on one page, I have want to show a template  in two version depending on the user's device.

For example, I implemented the following code.

```
<div class="desktop">
  <body>
    Hi Desktop user
  </body>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
  <body>
    Hi mobile
  </body>
</div>
```

This works okay with media queries but with javascript, I realized that `$('body')` actually returns both objects. Although the user doesn't see the element because `.desktop` is set to `display:none` on mobile deviecs, it seems that the html elements are rendered. In this case, is it still an okay practice or should I avoid doing something like this?

Comment: There must be only single body tag per html page.

Comment: Refer [Multiple <html><body> </html></body> in same file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file)

Comment: A hidden element is still part of DOM. You can use `$("body:visible")` to target the visible element (but fix the double-body issue first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, this is not very good practice. Because you have 2 elements on page, which browser will render. And for him ( browser ) it doesn't meter, visible this element or not.
Your media query from css can do all the same things on one element. And it will be faster. Or use server side to understand what kind of template you should show - mobile or desktop.