# Jquery detect element type in if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery http://jsfiddle.net/gg9xnkqq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if( $('.one').hasClass('one') ){
        $('.one').css({ 'color' : '#f00' });
    }
});
```

and this HTML

```
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<div class="one">dfv</div>
<span class="one">oiuoiuioou</span>
```

In the if statement, how can I detect if the type of the element with the class `one` is not `body`?

So all elements that are not `body` and have a certain class, will have their class changed.

Comment: `if( $('.one').hasClass('one') ){` will only ever be true, you can remove that

Comment: Not...`body`? I see `div` and `span`, not `body`...

Answer (score 3):

Since there is only 1 body you can select the elements as follows `$('body .one')` that way it'll select all the elements with class `one` inside the body.

Comment: I wish I'd had the common sense to think of that first... :)

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file multiple body tags are invalide. So nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('.one').not('body').css({ 'color' : '#f00' });
```

This will

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

Therefore, there is no need for the `if`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `not()`:

```
$('.one').not('body').css({ 'color' : '#f00' });
```

Or `:not()`:

```
$('.one:not("body")').css({ 'color' : '#f00' });
```

Or `filter()`:

```
$('.one').filter(':not("body")').css({ 'color' : '#f00' });
```

Or:

```
$('.one').filter(function () {
    return $(this).not('body');
}).css({ 'color' : '#f00' });
```

What you ***don't*** need to do is:

```
if( $('.one').hasClass('one') ){
    $('.one').css({ 'color' : '#f00' });
}
```

Because if the elements didn't have the class of `one` they wouldn't have been selected by the selector comprising of the class-name `one`.

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).