# How to set value for body in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` in which it contains a `body` element as follows:

```
<div id = "TextBox1">
<iframe id = "TextBox1_1">
#document
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Now I want to set a value to the `body` and tried

```
$('#TextBox1').attr('body', "SomeValue");
```

But it is not showing any value. How can this be done

Comment: what is `FreeTextBox1_designEditor`??

Comment: I am making an assumption here but I believe you are going to be making invalid HTML due to have multiple body tags. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file .

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web Here you go!

Comment: Assume that is the only body tag and tell me how can I set the value @Saar

Comment: Assuming that is the only body tag, the div should be inside of it and not the other way around.

Comment: I have got a `dll` and it contains the structure as I mentioned in my question @IfTrue

Comment: I do not see anywhere in your question where you mention a dll. Additionally as others have said you have two elements with the same ID. Is the iframe going to be of the same domain as the main page? If not you will not be able to edit elements inside of it. Iframe is more of a "browser" than just another element. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript .

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but two elements can't have the same ID, and you've not close the ID string of the div.

So if I rewrite a little bit the code, then you should have :

```
<div id="TextBox1">
    <iframe id="iframe_TextBox1">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body></body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And then you do:

```
$("#iframe_TextBox1 > body").html("SomeValue");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have included the JQuery simply put an ID in to your Body tag

```
<body id="MyID" ></body>

$("#MyID").html("<div>The stuff I want to add to the body</div>");
```

or without an ID you can just put:

```
$("body").html("<div>The stuff I want to add to the body</div>");
```

IfTrue is correct that you can't access the body with the code above from outside the Iframe, however the page that is inside the frame could contain the code to change the body.

As for accessing it outside the iframe you could use the following:

```
         var ifrBody = $("#MyFrame").contents().find("body");
         $(ifrBody).html("<div>My Stuff goes here</div>");
```

but only if you are within the same domain... you will get access denied if you try to do this across different domains. It is a security feature to prevent cross site scripting.

Comment: Can I do `$('#TextBox1 body').html("<div>The stuff I want to add to the body</div>");` @jon

Comment: The body is inside of an iframe though.