# PHP - Require Adding Header Tags In Body

Tags: php, html

When I use pgp require it moves the head content on the included file into the body tags, I've explored questions somewhat related to my problem but none have solved my problem.
**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
<?php
    require '/home/sethfreeman/public_html/subdomains/gwd/navigation/header/header.html';
?>
```

**Included File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/css/header.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <script src="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Chrome Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/css/header.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="screen">
        <div class="container"></div>
        <script src="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://sethjfreeman.com/subdomains/gwd/assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why don't you require them at the correct position? Why do you force Chrome to guess where your code goes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file

Comment: Require isn't smart.  It's simply going to dump the contents of the required file where it's invoked.  If you want some code in the head portion, put that in a separate file and require it in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

"Require isn't smart. It's simply going to dump the contents of the required file where it's invoked. If you want some code in the head portion, put that in a separate file and require it in the correct place." - [Major Productions LLC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399584/major-productions-llc)

To close this question.