# How can i modify downloaded html in an ionic app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic, we're trying to build a reader app that downloads documents in html from a service and then displays them. I know how to modify html that is part of the ionic application itself, but the documents we download are displayed inside the ionic app. We want to add a search function that finds and highlights all occurrences of the entered words. We find them and highlight them by wrapping them in a span that has a css class that sets a yellow background. But it doesn't reflect the changes in the app.

The document is downloaded from the service and then wrapped in a div, here's what we have do far, this is a snippet from the document.html for the document page in the app and is where the downloaded content lives:

```
<ion-content id="content">
 <div [ngClass]="isNight ? 'night' : 'day'">
  <div [ngClass]="isSingle ? 'single' : 'double'">
   <div id="inputText" class="document" [innerHtml]="document | keepHtml" [ngStyle]="{'font-size': fontSize+'em' }"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</ioncontent>
```

The javascript that highlights the hits is, I've left out the search box stuff since it's really just boilerplate, the highlight method is where the problem lies:

```
highlight(keyword) {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
  inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(keyword, 'g'), "<span class=\"keyword\">" + keyword + "</span>");
}
```

If the user searched for "the", for example, after the highlight() method runs we should see every "the" in the document highlighted in yellow. But we don't. If we remove the "| keepHtml" from the div for the document, search works.

If we display the document html using an alert from the typescript method we see our changes, but if we run the javascript console in the browser and look at the html in the Dom of the browser, the changes we made are not there.

I know I'm missing something obvious or fundamental to ionic/angular but so far I can't see what it is. Maybe I'm so far off that nobody can help me but I thought I'd take a shot. Thanks for understanding.

Adding the keepHtml code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

/**
 * Generated class for the KeepHtmlPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class KeepHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `keepHtml` pipe code?

Comment: I'll assume you added your pipe to app.module.ts. Do the downloaded HTML documents have `<html>` and `<body>` tags in them?

Comment: There's an import in app.module.ts for the pipe and yes, the downloaded documents are complete and include <html> and <body> tags.

Comment: That might be the problem then. HTML files can only have 1 `<html>` and `<body>` tag in them, and when you paste the downloaded HTML file into your page it then has two `<html>` and `<body>` tags in it. More info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file).

Comment: well, we are getting rid of those, sorry, i had to go back and look at the code. The service marks it up with a <doc> tag around the body of the document. We pull that out and throw away everything else, including the html, header and body tags.

Comment: I just noticed your `replace` string is missing a `"` after the second `\"`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Typo, just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered the problem; ionic/angular thought our html was unsafe. We started sanitizing it before we added it back in and it works.

We actually found two solutions, one was to run a sanitizer in the page class (excuse me if my angular-speak is not quite right, I've lived through so many "Waves of the Future" that at this point in my career they're all starting to run together) with bypassSecurityTrustHtml and the other, surprisingly was to add the modified HTML back into this.document instead of element.innerHTML.

The second solution seems like black magic, I'm not sure I understand why it works. I actually prefer the first solution.