# h:outputText with full HTML Code changes my CSS classes

Tags: html, jsf

I have the following code:

```
            <h:outputText value="#{ticketEditController.ticket.descriptionHtmlText}"
                                                    escape="false" />
```

"descriptionHtmlText" contains a full HTML code:

```
<html>.....</html>
```

The HTML code is visible in my page and it´s fine but my layout will be changed, because some CSS classes will overwrite the classes from my template from the content in descriptionHtmlText.

Therefore I´m asking, if there is something like to put an "iframe" or something like this around my h:outputText ? So h:outputText is independent from the other content in my JSF page?

HTML content can be everything, here just an example:

```
    <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns:mv="http://macVmlSchemaUri" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta name=Titel content=""><meta name=Stichwörter content=""><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
 o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
 w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
 .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
 </style><![endif]--><style><!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Arial;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
 @font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
 a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
 a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
 p
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0cm;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0cm;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
 p.externalclass, li.externalclass, div.externalclass
    {mso-style-name:externalclass;
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0cm;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0cm;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
 span.E-Mail-Formatvorlage21
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
 span.msoIns
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    mso-style-name:"";
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:teal;}
 .MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
 @page WordSection1
    {size:595.0pt 842.0pt;
    margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 2.0cm 70.85pt;}
 div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 --></style></head><body bgcolor=white lang=DE link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;mso-fareast-language:EN-US'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;mso-fareast-language:EN-US'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0cm 0cm 0cm'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:12.0pt;color:black'>Von: </span></b><span style='font-size:12.0pt;color:black'>&lt;soundsnap.activehosted.com@ac.soundsnap.com&gt; im Auftrag von Soundsnap Team &lt;hello@soundsnap.com&gt;<br><b>Datum: </b>Mittwoch, 6. November 2019 um 19:47<br><b>An: </b>&lt;info@mydomain.com&gt;<br><b>Betreff: </b>Sound Collections #27: Break a Sweat<o:p></o:p></span></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div><div><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:.75pt'><span style='font-size:1.0pt'>A dose of energy-inducing sound effects for video games and workouts scenes. <o:p></o:p></span></p></div><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 align=left width="100%" style='width:100.0%;background:white;margin-left:-2.25pt;margin-right:-2.25pt;min-width: auto'><tr id=layout-row4434><td width="100%" valign=top style='width:100.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id="layout_table_dc487906376e96605f002838992c8f84f7681aa1"><div align=center><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;background:white;min-width: auto'><tr><td width="100%" valign=top style='width:100.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%' id=layout-row-margin4434><div align=center><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;background:white'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important' id=layout-row-padding4434><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%'><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr style='height:22.5pt'><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:22.5pt'><div><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr style='height:22.5pt'><td valign=top style='background:white;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:22.5pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4433><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id=layout-row-margin4433><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='background:white;padding:30.0pt 0cm 30.0pt 0cm;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important' id=layout-row-padding4433><div align=center><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr><td width="100%" valign=top style='width:100.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%'><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'><a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;i=312A394A1A2537"><span style='color:#045FB4;text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=136 height=26 id="_x0000_i1025" src="https://soundsnap.imgus11.com/public/79585cd10847c25f69c6d0fb9169494c.png?r=1491081650" alt="oundsnap Home"></span></a><o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4432><td valign=top style='padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt' id=layout-row-margin4432><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 13.5pt 0cm 13.5pt' id=layout-row-padding4432><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;outline: none;color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;text-decoration:inherit' id="text_div4309"><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><b><span style='font-size:27.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'>Sound Collections</span></b><span style='font-size:27.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4439><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt' id=layout-row-margin4439><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 13.5pt 6.75pt 13.5pt' id=layout-row-padding4439><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;outline: none;color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;text-decoration:inherit' id="text_div4316"><div><div><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#848D9C'>Explore these curated sound sets, hand-selected by professionals for<br>specific purposes, ready to throw into your projects today!</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;color:#848D9C'><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4440><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id=layout-row-margin4440><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important' id=layout-row-padding4440><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr style='height:18.75pt'><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:18.75pt;min-width: 100%'><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr style='height:18.75pt'><td valign=top style='background:white;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:18.75pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4435><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id=layout-row-margin4435><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%' id=layout-row-padding4435><div align=center><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr><td width="100%" valign=top style='width:100.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%'><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'><a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;i=312A394A1A2545"><span style='color:#045FB4;text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=500 height=182 id="_x0000_i1026" src="https://soundsnap.imgus11.com/public/96b962e344944561e0376750f7b3d98a.jpg?r=2002838401" alt="reak a Sweat"></span></a><o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4441><td valign=top style='padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt' id=layout-row-margin4441><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:6.75pt 13.5pt 6.75pt 13.5pt' id=layout-row-padding4441><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;outline: none;color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;text-decoration:inherit' id="text_div4318"><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'>Break a Sweat</span></b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4442><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 11.25pt 0cm 11.25pt' id=layout-row-margin4442><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 13.5pt 0cm 13.5pt' id=layout-row-padding4442><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;outline: none;color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;text-decoration:inherit' id="text_div4319"><div><div><div><div><div><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#848D9C'>A dose of energy-inducing sound effects for video games and workouts scenes.<br><br><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div></div></div></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4443><td valign=top style='padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt' id=layout-row-margin4443><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 13.5pt 6.75pt 13.5pt;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important' id=layout-row-padding4443><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr><td style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%' id="html_div4320"><div style='margin-top:18.0pt;margin-bottom:18.0pt;outline: none;word-break:break-word'><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;line-height:150%;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:150%;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:gray'><br><a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;i=312A394A1A2545" target="_blank"><span style='border:solid #333333 1.5pt;padding:11.0pt;background:white'>Listen Now</span></a><br>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4444><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id=layout-row-margin4444><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%' id=layout-row-padding4444><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr style='height:60.0pt'><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:60.0pt;min-width: 100%'><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr style='height:60.0pt'><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:60.0pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4436><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id=layout-row-margin4436><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='background:whitesmoke;padding:30.0pt 0cm 16.5pt 0cm;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important' id=layout-row-padding4436><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%' id="text_div4313"><div><div><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><strong><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#111111'>Stay in touch by following us on</span></strong><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;color:#111111'><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4437><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id=layout-row-margin4437><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='background:whitesmoke;padding:0cm 0cm 42.0pt 0cm;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important' id=layout-row-padding4437><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%'><tr><td style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;min-width: 100%'><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;outline: none'><div align=center><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='outline: none'><tr><td width=48 style='width:36.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:1.0pt'><a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;i=312A394A1A2539"><span style='color:#045FB4;text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=48 height=48 id="_x0000_i1027" src="http://soundsnap.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-facebook.png"></span></a><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></td><td width=15 style='width:11.25pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;display:inline-block!important;width:15px!important'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:1.0pt'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=48 style='width:36.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;display:inline-block!important;width:48px!important'><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:1.0pt'><a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;i=312A394A1A2540"><span style='color:#045FB4;text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=48 height=48 id="_x0000_i1028" src="http://soundsnap.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-twitter.png"></span></a><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></td><td width=15 style='width:11.25pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;display:inline-block!important;width:15px!important'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:1.0pt'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=48 style='width:36.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;display:inline-block!important;width:48px!important'><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:1.0pt'><a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;i=312A394A1A2541"><span style='color:#045FB4;text-decoration:none'><img border=0 width=48 height=48 id="_x0000_i1029" src="http://soundsnap.img-us6.com/_social_/flat-color-round-instagram.png"></span></a><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id=layout-row4438><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm' id=layout-row-margin4438><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%;border-collapse:initial !important'><tr><td valign=top style='background:white;padding:39.75pt 11.25pt 21.75pt 11.25pt' id=layout-row-padding4438><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;min-width: 100%'><tr><td valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;outline: none;color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;text-decoration:inherit' id="text_div4315"><div><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><em><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'>Copyright ©2018 Soundsnap </span></em><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'><br><br>Our Mailing Address Is: </span></b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'>Ojoo Limited<br>Bouboulinas 11<br>1060 Nicosia<br>Cyprus</span><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'>Want to change how you receive these emails?</span><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'><o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;mso-element:frame;mso-element-wrap:around;mso-element-anchor-vertical:paragraph;mso-element-anchor-horizontal:column;mso-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'>You can <a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;i=312A394A1A2542" target="_blank"><span style='color:#045FB4'>update your preferences</span></a> or <a href="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/proc.php?nl=1&amp;c=312&amp;m=394&amp;s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;act=unsub" target="_blank"><span style='color:#045FB4'>unsubscribe from this list</span></a></span><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'><o:p></o:p></span></p></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table><p class=MsoNormal><img border=0 width=1 height=1 id="_x0000_i1030" src="https://soundsnap.emlnk1.com/lt.php?nl=1&amp;c=312&amp;m=394&amp;s=8d95d96e2df1d685d3d000245040aa5f&amp;l=open"><br clear=all><o:p></o:p></p></div></body></html>
```

Many thanks for help

Edit:
I´ve tried now:

```
<iframe
                                                                src="/admin/ticketsystem/ticketCommentHtmlOutput.xhtml?ticketCommentId=#{ticketComment.idHash}"></iframe>
```

I´ve create a new XHTML page:

```
  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="#{ticketCommentHtmlOutputController.htmlOutput}" escape="true"/>
</h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

Here my bean:

```
@ViewScoped
```

@Named
public class TicketCommentHtmlOutputController implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2815796004558360299L;
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TicketCommentHtmlOutputController.class);

@EJB
private TicketCommentService ticketCommentService;

private String htmlOutput;
private String ticketCommentId;

/**
 * Init
 */
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    LOGGER.info("START init");

    try {
        if (ticketCommentId == null)
            ticketCommentId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
                    .get("ticketCommentId");

        if (ticketCommentId != null) {

            ////////////////////////
            ////////////////////////
            //// SecurityCheck

            List<ObjectForSearchList> searchList = new ArrayList<ObjectForSearchList>();
            searchList = new ArrayList<ObjectForSearchList>();
            searchList.add(new ObjectForSearchList("idHash", ticketCommentId));
            TicketComment ticketComment = ticketCommentService.findTicketCommentByQuery(searchList);

            if (ticketComment == null) {
                htmlOutput = null;
            }

            ////////////////////////
            ////////////////////////
            ////////////////////////

            htmlOutput = ticketComment.getCommentHtmlText();
        }

        if (ticketCommentId == null) {
            htmlOutput = null;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
    }

    LOGGER.info("END init");
}

public String getHtmlOutput() {
    return htmlOutput;
}

public void setHtmlOutput(String htmlOutput) {
    this.htmlOutput = htmlOutput;
}

public String getTicketCommentId() {
    return ticketCommentId;
}

public void setTicketCommentId(String ticketCommentId) {
    this.ticketCommentId = ticketCommentId;
}
```

But my output is:
[image]

Comment: Please provide the code for `descriptionHtmlText` and clarify what is meant by _Therefore I´m asking, if there is something like to put an or something like this around my_

Comment: I have updated the code...

Comment: As your  h:outputText must reside in a html body, doesn't that finally render a <html><head></head><body><html><head></head><body></body></html></body></html> which is kind of a broken document tree?

Comment: The issue is, that CSS classes from the content in  h:outputText overrides my classes from the whole page.... Therefore I´m asking if I can create a iframe or something like this to have the content in  h:outputText completely independent from my whole layout...

Comment: No, the issue is (at least that is what I and @Selaron understand from your question) is that you have a broken dom tree with nested html, head and body tags. So you are in 'unspecified terrain' and fix that... No html, head and body in the outputext

Comment: No, my descriptionHtmlText  includes a full HTML page. It´s an HTML email...If I remove html, head, body from  descriptionHtmlText   than the Email will have not this CSS etc....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple <html><body> </html></body> in same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file)

Comment: YES, the issue is caused by the nested html tags YOU CREATED... Not a JSF thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035462/multiple-htmlbody-html-body-in-same-file.  and yes, you can always (and in this case should) create an iframe...

Comment: Ok, you mean I should do it like this: <iframe>     <h:outputText value="#{ticketEditController.ticket.descriptionHtmlText}"
                                                    escape="false" /> </iframe> ?

Comment: Iframes doesn't work like that. Use more like `<iframe src="urlOfYourTicketDescriptionHtmlTextServlet?id=#{ticketEditController.ticket.id}">`

Comment: @BalusC - this was helpful. many thanks. I will do that like that.

Comment: @BalusC; I´ve updated my post... It´s not working as expected... Any ideas?

Comment: Check the differences with your initial `h:outputText`... Should be an obvious cause... (and effectively this is a new question)... ;-)

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean. Or can I use something like <include ? Any ideas?